# services.db.environment needs a mapping

Tags: docker-compose

I am trying to create a compose for my recent project, but I'm having some problems with this indentation (I searched for similar solutions for this), since my bash can't compile my compose because of mapping issues on my environment mapping for database.

This is the part of the code my terminal is saying that needs revision.

```yaml
db:
   image: mysql:5.7
   container_name: pacoteiro-db
   restart: unless-stopped
   environment:
     - MYSQL_DATABASE: pacoteiro_db
     - MYSQL_USER: pacoteiro_db
     - MYSQL_PASSWORD: wasd
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wasdq
   ports:
     - '3306:3306'
   expose:
     - '3306:3306'
   volumes:
     - pacoteiro-db:/var/lib/mysql
   networks:
     - pacoteiro
```

I've looked into some of the documentation for docker-compose indentation, and it seems that my writing is fine, so i can't figure out what the problem is now.

Comment: Your YAML looks malformed. Everything under `db:` should be indented

Comment: sorry, i just pasted my code here, it's my first question here so i'm still getting the hang of it.

Comment: Exactly what error is being reported?

Comment: Your array syntax is off. It should be `- ENV_VAR_NAME=value`. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#set-environment-variables-in-containers

Comment: "services.db.environment must be a mapping" was the following error.

Comment: It was the equals on the variable, my vscode played me dirty this time by faking the correct separator. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The `services.db.environment` part needs a different syntax:

```
services:
  db:
    # ...

    environment:
       - MYSQL_DATABASE=pacoteiro_db
       - MYSQL_USER=pacoteiro_db
       - MYSQL_PASSWORD=wasd
       - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=wasdq

    # ...
```

See the official documentation for more information : [Environment variables in Compose | Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#set-environment-variables-in-containers)